# Digitalocean - More than one application running on the same droplet?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, digital-ocean

Is it possible to run more than one Rails application on the same DigitalOcean droplet?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend looking into using Dokku with Docker, which allows you to host applications along side each other. Digital Ocean has a One-click install available. I just started using it and deploying this way, and so far really like it.

**Here are some links:**

1. http://reallybusywizards.com/dokku-digitalocean-your-very-own-cheap-heroku-clone/
2. https://www.andrewmunsell.com/blog/dokku-tutorial-digital-ocean
3. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-dokku-one-click-digitalocean-image-to-run-a-node-js-app

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do this, you just need to configure your application server, I have done this using nginx, is very quiet. 
This tutorial is pretty cool to start with the server installer and rails application using Nginx server application:

[Tutorial DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-rails-and-nginx-with-passenger-on-ubuntu)

After doing this, open the configuration file for nginx:

```
  sudo nano /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
```

Now just add another block to configure a new application on another port, the default port is always 80. Enter note that port 8080 in this block.

```
      server { 
               listen 8080; 
               server_name example.com; 
               passenger_enabled on; 
               root /var/www/my_new_rails_app/public; 
             }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can I ask you to give me some tips how to set it up?

Comment: Thanks for details. I followed the tutorial, but my app doesn't work. If I try to access my app through IP address of the server, I get not found error. This is how my nginx.conf looks like: http://pastebin.com/qhtQdYvQ. My app is in /var/www/test (not the final rails app yet, just the index.html for the test).

Comment: @gabriel Your root should be pointed to public folder. Ex: root /var/www/test/public

Answer (score 1):

**YES**

I am doing this currently. If your using `Apache` then in your `httpd.conf` file simply make two entries pointing to the public folders of two different application. Remember to identify different address for each.

I use `phusion-passenger` to make rails run with `apache` and my setup looks like this;

```
<VirtualHost ####################.com:80>
    ServerName ####################.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/first_app/current/public/
    <Directory /var/www/html/first_app/current/public>
    Allow from all
    Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
    PassengerEnabled on
    #RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    #RewriteRule (.*) http://www.####################.com%{REQUEST_URI}
    SetEnv GEM_HOME /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost second_app.####################.com:80>
        ServerName second_app.####################.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/second_app/current/public/
        <Directory /var/www/html/second_app/current/public>
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
        </Directory>
        PassengerEnabled on
        #RewriteEngine On
        #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        #RewriteRule (.*) https://www.####################.com%{REQUEST_URI}
        SetEnv GEM_HOME /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I'm currently using unicorn, but I can migrate to Apache if it's better. Could you please give me some more instructions or a brief tutorial how to set things up?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem but @Leandro Figueredo answers didn't work for me.
Below i presenting what i do to achieve this.

Actually i have two website on one droplet.
I configured my server with this tutorial: [GoRails How to setup server with Ubuntu 14.04 and nginx](https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/14.04)

After this configure file **/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env    production;
    root         /home/user/appname/current/public;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
}

server {
       listen 80;
       listen [::]:80;
       server_name second_site.com www.second_site.com;
       passenger_enabled on;
       root /home/user/second_app/current/public;
}
```

**Important:**
remove default_server; from first server block

Comment: How or Where do you tell your application which domain is doing the request?